# Add a delay with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay

I want to use the methode `.delay()` to wait 1 sec before changing the content of an element. In my page, I have a button and when the ajax request is done, the button diplays "done". After that, I want to wait 1 sec and display "download". But the problem is that "download" is displayed immediately after the "done" without the delay.

Here is my code :

```
 $('#chocobo').click(function(){
   $('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></div>&nbspLoading');
   $.post("includes/modlist/pack.php",function(data){
        //$('#banana').addClass("fa-spin");
        $('#chocobo').addClass('done');
        $('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-check"></div>&nbspDone');
        $('#chocobo').delay(1000).html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-refresh"></div>&nbspDownload');        
   });
});
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think leveraging `delay()` is best used here. You're fine with just using a `setTimeout`. Observe the following...

```
[...]

$('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-check"></div>&nbspDone');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-refresh"></div>&nbspDownload');  
}, 1000);

[...]
```

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

See the [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) docs for example usages and scenarios

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ka7gx5/) - simplified demo

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I tried this method once but it didn't work, I probably made a mistake. But now it's ok, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery delay function is used for things added to a queue, like steps of an animation. You could try using the setTimeout instead to get the effect you're looking for:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-refresh"></div>&nbsp; Download');
}, 1000); // 1000 being 1s in ms
```

EDIT: Whoops! I was too slow. Erlaunis has the better answer anyway too.

Answer (score 1):

However, you can use it on this way, with callback function for `fadeIn()`, if you don't want to use setTimeout():

http://jsfiddle.net/ufsxaxm3/1/

```
$( "#chocobo" ).html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-check"></div>&nbspDone').fadeIn('slow', function() {
$('#chocobo').html('<div id="banana" class="fa fa-refresh"></div>&nbspDownload').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
  });;
```

So, you need some jquery effect/animation, and then delay() will work as you wish...

Comment: nice possibility, I'd lean towards this being a bit overkill and favoring a leaner method. Regardless nice find

Comment: Thanks, yes... just one more possibility... Native js setTimeout() is probably faster and even more elegant... but i like to use what jQuery offers (if library is already used)... :)